Parallel Convex Hull Algorithm for 2D Convex Hull of a Simple Polygon
I have a list (with lets say 600) of simple polygons (i.e. no self-intersections) with at least 4 and at max 3000 points.
I want to compute the convex hulls for each of these polygons on the GPU. That is, I need 600 convex hulls in the end.
Melkman's convex hull algorithm is a popular choice for simple polygons with a runtime of O(n). However, this algorithm is not parallel. Of course, I could compute the convex hull of all polygons in parallel with one thread for each input polygon. But I am looking for something that is parallel for each polygon.
In the literature, I did not find anything suitable. Most papers deal with arbitrary point clouds as input, where the filtering step is done in parallel on the GPU. The result of the filtering is then a simple polygon which is used as input for Melkman's algo.
But since I already start with a simple polygon for which I need the convex hull, this does not help.
Is there parallel convex hull algo for simple polygons?

The (very) variable amount of point/polygon is a problem on GPU typically because of branch divergence. This is especially true with one thread per polygon. Most threads may be inactive is 1 polygon has 3000 points and most others have significantly less points. This results in poor performance. If you use 1 block per polygon, then it mostly fix this problem, but then you need enough point for all the threads in a block (eg. at least 64~128 on modern GPUs). With only 4 points, most thread of a block will be inactive resulting in poor performance in this case.

In such a case, one could use segmented approaches but they are generally far more expensive and complex. I do not think there is any silver-bullet in this case (assuming the number of point is variable for each polygon). If the number is the same for all polygon, then the problem is completely different. In such a case, I think multiple algorithms (i.e. multiple kernel implementation) are needed based on the number of of point/polygon.

Also please note that the distribution of probability of the number of polygon matters too. For example, if in most case, there are only few points/polygon, then you can use a specialized implementation for this case. Convex-hull on 4~5 points is relatively trivial to perform as opposed to 3000 points.

There is a paper (see below), where its author proposes an algorithm, which you are looking for:

H. Wagener, "Optimal parallel hull construction for simple polygons in O(log log n) time", Proc. 33rd Annual Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science, pp.593-599, 1992. (Downloadable from SciHub).

However, this paper is old. Fortunately, there is another (and more recent) paper, where the Wagener algorithm is discussed together with its implementation in CUDA:

Colm O Dunlaing, "CUDA implementation of Wagener’s 2D convex hull PRAM algorithm", arXiv:1203.5004v2, 23 Mar 2012.

I didn't play with this algorithm myself, so this answer is essentially only a couple of links - however it might be a start for you.

I'm a bit conflicted about this answer. On one side it seems very promising, on the other hand it's a link-only answer which is discouraged on SO (because links die). At the same time I don't know if one can expect a complete replication of the algorithm here. I think there should be at least some description of the algorithm/its basic idea, even if it's just citations from the paper(s).

In the end, Colm Ó Dúnlaing, the author of the second paper, writes "When run on the dataset illustrated, our CUDA algorithm is perceptibly slower by comparison
with a serial algorithm (which is not described here). This is not surprising considering the serialisation of conflicting memory accesses. To attempt optimal speedup as described here would demand a great deal of effort. Our CUDA program is a specimen implementation of a PRAM algorithm which cannot claim much speed advantage." So maybe it's not as promising as I thought.

@paleonix - I completely agree with your critique. I'll update my answer to make it more linky independent. As for the algorithm itself, and it's implementation in cuda - it looks like much more needs to be done to make it useful.

I mean who knows maybe when applying the algorithm to many smaller polygons instead of one big one, the memory congestion is not as much of an issue. Or the author benchmarked a case that was not big enough for the GPU to benefit.

Thanks for the paper! There are interesting ideas in it. Maybe I can combine some things from it with my existing approach.

The (older) paper is only behind a paywall on the IEEE website; it's freely available on SciHub.

Why not use physics? Assume all points as atoms. Each atom exerts a force to every other or even only within a close distance neighborhood. Convex hull atoms (surface atoms) would have the highest force acting on them because they have no opposing atoms on outside to neutralize the inner force. So, one can compute the forces using FFT (O(nlogn)) based convolution and sort the atoms on their net force vector length (O(nlogn)). Then start selecting them until one is found inside the selected atoms found (O(h^2) where h is number of convex hull points).

FFT is parallelized, cuda even has a feature to do it in-kernel.
sorting is parallelized (like bitonic sort or similar)
checking if a point is inside selected points, can also be parallelized

3000 points (3 dimensions, 32bit each) takes 36kB data and fits inside shared memory inside a SM unit of CUDA architecture. So a polygon can be computed by a single block of threads (64-1024 threads).
For chaotic number of work per task (polygon), a parent kernel can be launched, then it can spawn child kernels with variable amount of threads depending on selected polygon and then compute them with that optimal number of threads. This way, number of threads wasted is decreased. Dynamic parallelism reduces the launch overhead (instead of launching child kernels from host).

Interesting idea! However, if we want for each point to calculate something, processing all other points - then, maybe, that something can be the existence of a half-plane, containing all other points?

What an interesting idea! Is there already a paper with this idea worked out? Love the analogy!

For low number of points, yes, all pair computations would be fast too.  I don't know any paper about this. I'm a physics engineer with 100% of experience on software development. So I thought a physics approach could be simple to implement (but not sure about performance for all GPUs as some GPUs may have smaller shared memory).

One problem with this approach that it cannot discern between global and local force maxima. Think of a pocket between two points that truly belong to the convex hull. All points inside this pocket should not contribute to the final hull. However, a spike in this pocket that almost reaches the connection line between the two convex hull points would look exactly like a point that truly belongs to the hull.

@Merlin1896 Do you mean pockets after convex hull algorithm or before the algorithm? What if its concave? I mean, if we zoom enough, anything is concave due to presence of atoms. There has to be a scale parameter to decide to smooth-out effects of pockets that are small enough.

Assume points p and q of the polyline belong to the convex hull. All points between p and q are points of a pocket. These points lie inside the hull and not on the border of the hull. But the structure of the points between p and q may be such that there is a peak which goes almost to the line (of the CH) from p to q. This peak will then locally look like a possible point for the convex hull. Only if all points of the polyline are considered, we can figure out that the peak is inside a pocket and only a local maximum. I doubt that these situations can be reliably resolved with your approach.

@Merlin1896 then I guess that structure of the vertices do not look like uniform separation of atoms. Then yes, it would be not computable.
